# How can I access to my nodeJS app in console on my server?

Tags: node.js, console

I have an application nodeJS started like a deamon with forever(https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever).

So now, how can I access to my app and be abble to watch and change values of variables with SSH connexion on my server?

How open console on my app without interuption of service?

thx.

Comment: You can't. Your app shouldn't depend on you changing variables while it's still running.

Comment: How can I debug if we can't view or change variables?! :|

Comment: You should be doing that locally on your own machine

Comment: In local, I don't have the context when I'm online with others users using my app... So it's not what i need!

Answer (score 0):

You should give [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) a look.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing built-in for that.

However, you can create a function on the server that will eval whatever string you put as parameter.

To query that function, you can use ajax or socket.io for example.

Socket.io example

```
    socket.on('evalStr', function (str) { eval(str);}); //server
    socket.emit('evalStr', "myVar = 10;"); //client via console
```

Edit: Of course, you can add security such as testing a password before evaluating.

Comment: `socket.emit('evalStr', 'dropAllDatabasesPerformDDOSAttackAndSend1000000000SpamEmails()')`

Comment: `socket.emit('evalStr',{password:"secret",command:"x=10"});` and on server side, you test password before eval the command.

Comment: There actually is [something built-in for that](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

Comment: @vrmc I try debug mode, but fail at the first test: ```var test = 42;``` in server.js (I don't forget reload server). ```debug> console.log(test)
ReferenceError: test is not defined``` I conclude this debug mode create a new instance of server, so it's like comment on my question where it said "test in local server", but I want to watch and modify in real time the true variable on the true online nodeJS server, not an another instance !

Comment: I would guess that `test` is not defined in that context because it's not a global variable. Node automatically wraps each source file in a closure to create private modules. Change it to `test = 42;` (without the `var`) and it might work.

Comment: @vrmc it's not^^ I try with and without "var", with and without "document." or "window.", nothing works... always undefined...